# Change any type of string to Title Case in Javascript

Tags: javascript, string

I want to write a function which can change any type of string case i.e lower case, UPPER CASE, camelCase, snake_case, lisp-case into **Title Case**

I am not looking for something bvery complicated, just a simple one or two liner.

I tried using soem regexp such as this

```
function(input) {
    return input.replace(/([^\W_]+[^\s_]*) */g, function(txt){
        return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();
    });
};
```

It works for some cases but does not work in all cases

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
var titleCase = oldString
               .replace(/([a-z])([A-Z])/g, function (allMatches, firstMatch, secondMatch) {
                     return firstMatch + " " + secondMatch;
               })
               .toLowerCase()
               .replace(/([ -_]|^)(.)/g, function (allMatches, firstMatch, secondMatch) {
                     return (firstMatch ? " " : "") + secondMatch.toUpperCase();
               }
);
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y9mu5hma/3/)**

**[Working Fiddle2](http://jsfiddle.net/y9mu5hma/4/)**

Comment: Sorry ! but this does not change the Desired Case, It will only capitalize the first letter.. I want something to change "email_template" to "Email Template"

Comment: @GiedriusD updated.. I think this is working fine now.

Answer (score 5):

```
function titleCase(s) { 
    return s
        .replace(/([^A-Z])([A-Z])/g, '$1 $2') // split cameCase
        .replace(/[_\-]+/g, ' ') // split snake_case and lisp-case
        .toLowerCase()
        .replace(/(^\w|\b\w)/g, function(m) { return m.toUpperCase(); }) // title case words
        .replace(/\s+/g, ' ') // collapse repeated whitespace
        .replace(/^\s+|\s+$/, ''); // remove leading/trailing whitespace
}
```

Example:

```
['UPPER CASE', 'camelCase', 'snake_case', 'lisp-case'].map(titleCase)
// result: ["Upper Case", "Camel Case", "Snake Case", "Lisp Case"]
```

Comment: Woah so many regexes..!! I am sure they can be refactored to a single line.

Comment: @Mr_Green what's the point? They're perfectly readable as is.

Comment: @Mr_Green you can leave out last two if you have clean input. Also it may be possible to factor splitting into single regex but at the cost of readability.

Comment: @GiedriusD agreed.. +1